# Download size: Ubuntu 14.04 ISO image vs online upgrade?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, downloads

The .iso file that I can download from Ubuntu's website is 970MB.

How much space will it be if I install through this notification that came? Does an upgrade download less data?
 [image: install 14.04 prompt]

Comment: -1; Please clarify what exactly your problem is.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki Hello, I don't suggest downvoting unclear questions. If you feel it needs clarification, you can simply comment without downvoting, or issue a "vote to close" with "unclear what you're asking" or flag it "very low quality", so it doesn't lose visibility (which downvoting does). Personally I thought the question was clear and understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That notification will upgrade your system in-place by downloading the updated packages and installing them.

It's likely that most of the base packages will need to be downloaded and updated, so I don't think you would save a lot of time by doing that.